# Deserialize Java LinkedList

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

This is how LinkedList implements readObject from Serializable

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
{
      // Read in any hidden serialization magic
      s.defaultReadObject();

      // Read in size
      int size = s.readInt();

      // Read in all elements in the proper order.
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          linkLast((E)s.readObject());
}
```

I generally managed to serialize it to file by

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("list.ser");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(list);
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

An attempt to restore the list from file in a similar way (oos.readObject()) end with OptionalDataException.
What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Would you give the full code?  It should be as simple as `ObjectInputStream` and using the `readObject` method.

Comment: Could we see the exact code you use to restore the list?

Comment: Is `oos` in `oos.readObject()` the `ObjectOutputStream`?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what this question is about. Why are you showing us code from LinkedList - that should really be working however it happens to be implemented? What's in your list? Where is the exception coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, I think.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("list.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    List list = (List) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
```

It would be a good idea to read the javadoc for [`OptionalDataException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OptionalDataException.html).  It goes into details of the situations where the exception may be thrown.  This should provide some clues to help figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is in the fact that you are serializing objects of unknown type (E). While the first approach works because you add explicit cast, the second one fails because Java cannot cast to unknown type E. That's my guess, might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not in `LinkedList`. Those basic types can always be (de-)serialized. But the list is only a tiny fraction of the picture: Serialization will only work if all the objects **in** the list can be (de-)serialized, too.

So my guess is that the exception is thrown in a different place. Make sure that each object in the list behaves.